# suma de monedas par amáquina expendedora

Tags: java, java-swing

Estoy haciendo un dispensador de chocolates y quiero hacer que para pagar el usuario haga clicks en las monedas y éstas se vayan sumando y que el resultado de la suma se vaya escribiendo en el `Jlabel` donde dice dinero depositado, he intentado varias maneras sin resultados. 
De igual manera he intentado realizarlo con

```
if(e.getSource()==boton1){
cambio.setText("1");
```

sin embargo me manda una serie de excepciones que no entiendo.
Si no puedo realizarlo asi me gustaria hacerlo de la manera mas sencilla posible solo sumando los valores y poniendo el resultado final en la caja de texto donde dice dinero depositado en lugar de ir sumando y escribiendo el resultado cada vez que presionas una moneda

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    // Raul Alonso Gaitan Lara
// Proyecto programacion
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class GuiProyecto1 extends JFrame {


    JLabel producto,informacion, cambio;
    JButton b1,b2,pagar;


    public GuiProyecto1 () {
        super("Dispensador de chocolates");
        setLayout(null);
        setSize(850,500);
        setVisible(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


        JPanel pizq = new JPanel();

        JPanel pder= new JPanel();

        JPanel superpanel=new JPanel();

        JLabel producto= new JLabel();

        JLabel j = new JLabel();

        cambio=new JLabel();


        superpanel.setLayout(null);
        superpanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        superpanel.setSize(860,510);

        informacion= new JLabel();




        j.setBounds(500,380,140,40);
        // j.setOpaque(true);
        // j.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        j.setText("Dinero depositado:");
        j.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        j.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        j.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        j.setFont(new Font("arial",1,15));


        pizq.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));

        pizq.setBounds(50,20,400,300);
        // pizq.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

        pder.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));

        pder.setBounds(500,100,300,230);
        pder.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        // pder.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

        // caracterisiticas del JLabel informacion
        // informacion.setText("Aqui va el pecio y el nombre del producto");
        informacion.setBounds(500,15,300,80);

        informacion.setOpaque(true);

        informacion.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        informacion.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

        informacion.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

        // caracterisicas del JLabel producto
        // producto.setText("Aqui esta su producto");


        producto.setOpaque(true);

        producto.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        producto.setBounds(50,370,400,50);


        cambio.setBounds(650,380,100,40);
        cambio.setOpaque(true);
        cambio.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        cambio.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        cambio.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);






        //añadir botones
        JButton b1= new JButton("a");
        pizq.add(b1);
        b1.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

        JButton b2= new JButton("b");
        pizq.add(b2);
        b2.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

        JButton b3= new JButton("c");
        pizq.add(b3);
        b3.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

        JButton b4= new JButton("d");
        pizq.add(b4);
        b4.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

        JButton b5= new JButton("e");
        pizq.add(b5);
        b5.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

        JButton b6= new JButton("f");
        pizq.add(b6);
        b6.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

        JButton b7= new JButton("g");
        pizq.add(b7);
        b7.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

        JButton b8= new JButton("h");
        pizq.add(b8);
        b8.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

        JButton b9= new JButton("i");
        pizq.add(b9);
        b9.setForeground(Color.WHITE);


        // Crear action listeners
        b1.addActionListener(new BotonPulsadoListener());
        b2.addActionListener(new BotonPulsadoListener());
        b3.addActionListener(new BotonPulsadoListener());
        b4.addActionListener(new BotonPulsadoListener());
        b5.addActionListener(new BotonPulsadoListener());
        b6.addActionListener(new BotonPulsadoListener());
        b7.addActionListener(new BotonPulsadoListener());
        b8.addActionListener(new BotonPulsadoListener());
        b9.addActionListener(new BotonPulsadoListener());

        // Cambiar color de botones
        b1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        b2.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        b3.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        b4.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        b5.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        b6.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        b7.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        b8.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        b9.setBackground(Color.WHITE);



        // creo imagenes

        ImageIcon ferrero = new ImageIcon("ferrero.jpg");

        ImageIcon hershey = new ImageIcon("hershey.jpg");

        ImageIcon carlosv = new ImageIcon("carlosv.jpg");

        ImageIcon reeces = new ImageIcon("reeces.jpg");

        ImageIcon kitkat = new ImageIcon("kitkat.jpg");

        ImageIcon crunch = new ImageIcon("crunch.jpg");

        ImageIcon larin = new ImageIcon("larin.jpg");

        ImageIcon snicker = new ImageIcon("snicker.jpg");

        ImageIcon baby = new ImageIcon("baby.jpg");



        // añadimos las imagenes a los botones Y redimensiono al tamaño del boton

        b1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ferrero.getImage().getScaledInstance(100,100,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH )));

        b2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(hershey.getImage().getScaledInstance(100,100,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH )));

        b3.setIcon(new ImageIcon(carlosv.getImage().getScaledInstance(100,100,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH )));

        b4.setIcon(new ImageIcon(reeces.getImage().getScaledInstance(100,130,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH )));

        b5.setIcon(new ImageIcon(kitkat.getImage().getScaledInstance(100,100,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH )));

        b6.setIcon(new ImageIcon(crunch.getImage().getScaledInstance(100,90,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH )));

        b7.setIcon(new ImageIcon(larin.getImage().getScaledInstance(100,130,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH )));

        b8.setIcon(new ImageIcon(snicker.getImage().getScaledInstance(100,90,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH )));

        b9.setIcon(new ImageIcon(baby.getImage().getScaledInstance(100,100,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH )));



        //añadimos botones al panel derecho
        JButton peso1 =new JButton("1");
        peso1.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        peso1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        pder.add(peso1);


        JButton peso2 =new JButton("2");
        peso2.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        peso2.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        pder.add(peso2);

        JButton peso5 =new JButton("3");
        peso5.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        peso5.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        pder.add(peso5);

        JButton peso10 =new JButton("4");
        peso10.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        peso10.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        pder.add(peso10);

        JButton pagar =new JButton("  Pagar  ");
        pagar.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        pder.add(pagar);

        JButton limpiar =new JButton(" Borrar ");
        limpiar.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        pder.add(limpiar);


        // crear imagenes para el panel derecho

        ImageIcon moneda1 = new ImageIcon("1peso.jpg");
        ImageIcon moneda2 = new ImageIcon("2pesos.jpg");
        ImageIcon moneda3 = new ImageIcon("5pesos.jpg");
        ImageIcon moneda4 = new ImageIcon("10pesos.jpg");


        // agregar imagenes a los botones

        peso1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(moneda1.getImage().getScaledInstance(75,75,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH )));
        peso2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(moneda2.getImage().getScaledInstance(75,75,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH )));
        peso5.setIcon(new ImageIcon(moneda3.getImage().getScaledInstance(75,75,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH )));
        peso10.setIcon(new ImageIcon(moneda4.getImage().getScaledInstance(75,75,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH )));





        // action listeners panel derecho

        peso1.addActionListener(new botonCambio());

        peso2.addActionListener(new botonCambio());

        peso5.addActionListener(new botonCambio());

        peso10.addActionListener(new botonCambio());

        pagar.addActionListener(new botonCambio());

        limpiar.addActionListener(new botonCambio());






        superpanel.add(pizq);
        superpanel.add(pder);
        superpanel.add(informacion);
        superpanel.add(producto);
        superpanel.add(j);
        superpanel.add(cambio);
        add(superpanel);
    }



        int cantidadA=0;
        int cantidadB=0;
        int cantidadC=0;
        int cantidadD=0;


            public static void main (String [] args){

                GuiProyecto1 ventana =new GuiProyecto1();
            }

            public class BotonPulsadoListener implements ActionListener{
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

            switch(e.getActionCommand()){
                case "a": informacion.setText(" Chocolate ferrero $8 ");
                break;
                case"b": informacion.setText(" Chocolate Hershey $13 ");
                break;
                case "c": informacion.setText(" Chocolate Carlos V $5 ");
                break;
                case "d": informacion.setText(" Chocolate Reeses $12");
                break;
                case "e": informacion.setText(" Chocolate KitKat $20 ");
                break;
                case "f": informacion.setText(" Chocolate Crunch $9");
                break;
                case "g": informacion.setText(" Chocolate Larin $4 ");
                break;
                case "h": informacion.setText(" Chocolate Snicker $7 ");
                break;
                case "i": informacion.setText(" Chocolate Baby Ruth $10 ");
                break;
            }

        }


    }


        public class botonCambio implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
                int contador=0;
                String f1="Favor de ingresar las monedas";
                String f2= "Su cambio es: $ ";
                String f3="Deposite mas monedas!";
                String f4= "Recoja su producto";

                int p1=8;
                int p2=13;
                int p3=5;
                int p4=12;
                int p5=20;
                int p6=9;
                int p7=4;
                int p8=7;
                int p9=10;

                int contador1=0;

                int contador2=0;

                int contador3=0;

                int contador4=0;

                int contadortotal=0;

                //contador=Integer.parseInt(cambio.getText().toString());

                switch(ae.getActionCommand()){



                    case "1":   cambio.setText(" "); 
                                cambio.setText("1");

                                contador=Integer.parseInt(cambio.getText().toString());
                                cantidadA++;
                                contador1=contador*cantidadA;
                                contadortotal=contadortotal+contador1;
                                cambio.setText(""+contadortotal);
                                //cambio.setText(""+contador);

                    break;

                    case "2":   cambio.setText(" "); 
                                cambio.setText("2");

                                contador=Integer.parseInt(cambio.getText().toString());
                                cantidadB++;
                                contador2=contador*cantidadB;
                                contadortotal=contadortotal+contador2;
                                cambio.setText(""+contadortotal);

                    break;

                    case "3":   cambio.setText(" ");
                                cambio.setText("5");

                                contador=Integer.parseInt(cambio.getText().toString());
                                cantidadC++;
                                contador3=contador*cantidadC;
                                contadortotal=contadortotal+contador3;
                                cambio.setText(""+contadortotal);
                    break;
                    case "4":   cambio.setText(" ");
                                cambio.setText("10");

                                contador=Integer.parseInt(cambio.getText().toString());
                                cantidadD++;
                                contador4=contador*cantidadD;
                                contadortotal=contadortotal+contador4;
                                cambio.setText(""+contadortotal);
                    break;

                    case "paga": //cambio.setText(""+contadortotal);
                    break;
                }






            //contador=cambio.getText();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: me parece que contador total esta de mas y entregale el valor de contador 2 al label, es decir, cambio.setText(""+contador2);

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, ya lo modifiqué y si se suman los botones por independiente, es decir si el usario hace click en la moneda de un peso, el jLabel escribe "1", si le vuelve a hacer click el jlabel dice "2", pero si despues hace click en la moneda de 5 pesos por ejemplo, el jLabel dice "5", y lo que yo quiero es que lo sume con las monedas anteriores, es decir que diga "7" y no "5"

Comment: Para el bien de la lectura, deberías compartir el código escrito, no en imagen.

Comment: Bien hecho, seguro tu profe no explica nada. Y vienes aquí a pedir ayuda.

Comment: Lamentablemente asi es, he hestado leyendo y viendo muchos videos para poder hacer lo que llevo pero ya me había trabado :C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si entiendi bien lo que quieres, este es el codigo.

Ojo: cambie la ubicacion del metodo setVisible(true); asi que copia y pega todo el codigo

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuiProyecto1 extends JFrame {


JLabel producto,informacion, cambio;
JButton b1,b2,pagar;


public GuiProyecto1 () {
    super("Dispensador de chocolates");
    setLayout(null);
    setSize(850,500);

    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


    JPanel pizq = new JPanel();

    JPanel pder= new JPanel();

    JPanel superpanel=new JPanel();

    JLabel producto= new JLabel();

    JLabel j = new JLabel();

    cambio=new JLabel();


    superpanel.setLayout(null);
    superpanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    superpanel.setSize(860,510);

    informacion= new JLabel();




    j.setBounds(500,380,140,40);
    // j.setOpaque(true);
    // j.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    j.setText("Dinero depositado:");
    j.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    j.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    j.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    j.setFont(new Font("arial",1,15));


    pizq.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));

    pizq.setBounds(50,20,400,300);
    // pizq.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

    pder.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));

    pder.setBounds(500,100,300,230);
    pder.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    // pder.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

    // caracterisiticas del JLabel informacion
    // informacion.setText("Aqui va el pecio y el nombre del producto");
    informacion.setBounds(500,15,300,80);

    informacion.setOpaque(true);

    informacion.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    informacion.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

    informacion.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

    // caracterisicas del JLabel producto
    // producto.setText("Aqui esta su producto");


    producto.setOpaque(true);

    producto.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    producto.setBounds(50,370,400,50);


    cambio.setBounds(650,380,100,40);
    cambio.setOpaque(true);
    cambio.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    //cambio.setText("etiqueta cambio");
    cambio.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    cambio.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);






    //añadir botones
    JButton b1= new JButton("a");
    pizq.add(b1);
    b1.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

    JButton b2= new JButton("b");
    pizq.add(b2);
    b2.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

    JButton b3= new JButton("c");
    pizq.add(b3);
    b3.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

    JButton b4= new JButton("d");
    pizq.add(b4);
    b4.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

    JButton b5= new JButton("e");
    pizq.add(b5);
    b5.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

    JButton b6= new JButton("f");
    pizq.add(b6);
    b6.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

    JButton b7= new JButton("g");
    pizq.add(b7);
    b7.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

    JButton b8= new JButton("h");
    pizq.add(b8);
    b8.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

    JButton b9= new JButton("i");
    pizq.add(b9);
    b9.setForeground(Color.WHITE);


    // Crear action listeners
    b1.addActionListener(new BotonPulsadoListener());
    b2.addActionListener(new BotonPulsadoListener());
    b3.addActionListener(new BotonPulsadoListener());
    b4.addActionListener(new BotonPulsadoListener());
    b5.addActionListener(new BotonPulsadoListener());
    b6.addActionListener(new BotonPulsadoListener());
    b7.addActionListener(new BotonPulsadoListener());
    b8.addActionListener(new BotonPulsadoListener());
    b9.addActionListener(new BotonPulsadoListener());

    // Cambiar color de botones
    b1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    b2.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    b3.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    b4.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    b5.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    b6.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    b7.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    b8.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    b9.setBackground(Color.WHITE);



    // creo imagenes

    ImageIcon ferrero = new ImageIcon("ferrero.jpg");

    ImageIcon hershey = new ImageIcon("hershey.jpg");

    ImageIcon carlosv = new ImageIcon("carlosv.jpg");

    ImageIcon reeces = new ImageIcon("reeces.jpg");

    ImageIcon kitkat = new ImageIcon("kitkat.jpg");

    ImageIcon crunch = new ImageIcon("crunch.jpg");

    ImageIcon larin = new ImageIcon("larin.jpg");

    ImageIcon snicker = new ImageIcon("snicker.jpg");

    ImageIcon baby = new ImageIcon("baby.jpg");



    // añadimos las imagenes a los botones Y redimensiono al tamaño del boton

    b1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ferrero.getImage().getScaledInstance(100,100,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH )));

    b2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(hershey.getImage().getScaledInstance(100,100,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH )));

    b3.setIcon(new ImageIcon(carlosv.getImage().getScaledInstance(100,100,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH )));

    b4.setIcon(new ImageIcon(reeces.getImage().getScaledInstance(100,130,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH )));

    b5.setIcon(new ImageIcon(kitkat.getImage().getScaledInstance(100,100,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH )));

    b6.setIcon(new ImageIcon(crunch.getImage().getScaledInstance(100,90,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH )));

    b7.setIcon(new ImageIcon(larin.getImage().getScaledInstance(100,130,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH )));

    b8.setIcon(new ImageIcon(snicker.getImage().getScaledInstance(100,90,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH )));

    b9.setIcon(new ImageIcon(baby.getImage().getScaledInstance(100,100,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH )));



    //añadimos botones al panel derecho
    JButton peso1 =new JButton("1");
    peso1.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    peso1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    pder.add(peso1);


    JButton peso2 =new JButton("2");
    peso2.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    peso2.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    pder.add(peso2);

    JButton peso5 =new JButton("3");
    peso5.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    peso5.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    pder.add(peso5);

    JButton peso10 =new JButton("4");
    peso10.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    peso10.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    pder.add(peso10);

    JButton pagar =new JButton("  Pagar  ");
    pagar.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    pder.add(pagar);

    JButton limpiar =new JButton(" Borrar ");
    limpiar.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    pder.add(limpiar);


    // crear imagenes para el panel derecho

    ImageIcon moneda1 = new ImageIcon("1peso.jpg");
    ImageIcon moneda2 = new ImageIcon("2pesos.jpg");
    ImageIcon moneda3 = new ImageIcon("5pesos.jpg");
    ImageIcon moneda4 = new ImageIcon("10pesos.jpg");


    // agregar imagenes a los botones

    peso1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(moneda1.getImage().getScaledInstance(75,75,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH )));
    peso2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(moneda2.getImage().getScaledInstance(75,75,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH )));
    peso5.setIcon(new ImageIcon(moneda3.getImage().getScaledInstance(75,75,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH )));
    peso10.setIcon(new ImageIcon(moneda4.getImage().getScaledInstance(75,75,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH )));





    // action listeners panel derecho

    peso1.addActionListener(new botonCambio());

    peso2.addActionListener(new botonCambio());

    peso5.addActionListener(new botonCambio());

    peso10.addActionListener(new botonCambio());

    pagar.addActionListener(new botonCambio());

    limpiar.addActionListener(new botonCambio());






    superpanel.add(pizq);
    superpanel.add(pder);
    superpanel.add(informacion);
    superpanel.add(producto);
    superpanel.add(j);
    superpanel.add(cambio);
    add(superpanel);
    setVisible(true);
}



    int cantidadA=0;
    int cantidadB=0;
    int cantidadC=0;
    int cantidadD=0;


        public static void main (String [] args){

            GuiProyecto1 ventana =new GuiProyecto1();
        }

        public class BotonPulsadoListener implements ActionListener{
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

        switch(e.getActionCommand()){
            case "a": informacion.setText(" Chocolate ferrero $8 ");
            break;
            case"b": informacion.setText(" Chocolate Hershey $13 ");
            break;
            case "c": informacion.setText(" Chocolate Carlos V $5 ");
            break;
            case "d": informacion.setText(" Chocolate Reeses $12");
            break;
            case "e": informacion.setText(" Chocolate KitKat $20 ");
            break;
            case "f": informacion.setText(" Chocolate Crunch $9");
            break;
            case "g": informacion.setText(" Chocolate Larin $4 ");
            break;
            case "h": informacion.setText(" Chocolate Snicker $7 ");
            break;
            case "i": informacion.setText(" Chocolate Baby Ruth $10 ");
            break;
        }

    }


}


    public class botonCambio implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
            int contador=0;
            String f1="Favor de ingresar las monedas";
            String f2= "Su cambio es: $ ";
            String f3="Deposite mas monedas!";
            String f4= "Recoja su producto";

            int p1=8;
            int p2=13;
            int p3=5;
            int p4=12;
            int p5=20;
            int p6=9;
            int p7=4;
            int p8=7;
            int p9=10;

            int contador1=0;

            int contador2=0;

            int contador3=0;

            int contador4=0;

            int contadortotal=0;

            //contador=Integer.parseInt(cambio.getText().toString());

            switch(ae.getActionCommand()){



                case "1":   
                            if(cambio.getText().equals(""))
                             contador=0;
                            else
                            contador=Integer.parseInt(cambio.getText().toString());
                            contador1=contador+1;
                            cambio.setText(""+contador1);
                            //cambio.setText(""+contador);

                break;

                case "2":
                            if(cambio.getText().equals(""))
                             contador=0;
                            else
                            contador=Integer.parseInt(cambio.getText().toString());
                            contador2=contador+2;
                            cambio.setText(""+contador2);

                break;

                case "3":   
                             if(cambio.getText().equals(""))
                                contador=0;
                             else
                            contador=Integer.parseInt(cambio.getText().toString());
                            contador3=contador+5;
                            cambio.setText(""+contador3);
                break;
                case "4":   
                            if(cambio.getText().equals(""))
                                  contador=0;
                            else
                            contador=Integer.parseInt(cambio.getText().toString());
                            contador4=contador+10;
                            cambio.setText(""+contador4);
                break;

                case "paga": //cambio.setText(""+contadortotal);
                break;
            }






        //contador=cambio.getText();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Me ha servido, había estado mucho tiempo intentando resolver eso y no podía soy nuevo programando y no me funcionaba agradezco enormemente la ayuda y el tiempo

Comment: De nada @Alonso, un placer ayudar a alguien agradecido. Bendiciones.

Answer (score 0):

Espero y sea de tu ayuda lo hice por medio de consola solo tendrías que modificarlo para que lo muestre en el Jlabel, donde esta el * son las lineas que tendrías que colocar,  al momento de seleccionar un caso lo que hace es tomar el valor que tiene el jlabel y sumarlo al nuevo valor y después de eso colocarlo de nuevo en Jlabel con la nueva cantidad.

Coloque ventana.setText(), porque de manera rapida y cómo ejemplo no hice los atributos privados.

Creo que te hace falta tomar el valor actual y sumarlo al nuevo valor dependiendo la moneda, es por eso que no lo suma, solo te muestra el nuevo valor de la moneda

```
 System.out.printf("Ingresa un valor 1 , 2, 5, 10 : ");
            valor = teclado.nextInt();
            switch (valor){
                case 1:
                    // cantidad = cantidad + valor; 
                    //toma el valor actual lo convierte a entero y lo suma al nuevo valor
                   * cantidad = Integer.parseInt(ventana.texto.getText()) + valor; //valor = 1
                    System.out.println(" " +cantidad);
                   * ventana.texto.setText(" "); // Limpia el label 
                   * ventana.texto.setText(""+ cantidad); // Coloca el nuevo valor
                    break;
                case 2:

                   // cantidad = cantidad + valor;
                   * cantidad = Integer.parseInt(ventana.texto.getText()) + valor; //Valor = 2
                    System.out.println(" " +cantidad);
                   * ventana.texto.setText(" ");
                   * ventana.texto.setText(""+ cantidad);
                    break;
                case 5:
                   // cantidad = cantidad + valor;
                  *  cantidad = Integer.parseInt(ventana.texto.getText()) + valor;//Valor = 5
                    System.out.println(" " +cantidad);
                  *  ventana.texto.setText(" ");
                  *  ventana.texto.setText(""+ cantidad);
                    break;
                case 10:
                   // cantidad = cantidad + valor;
                   * cantidad = Integer.parseInt(ventana.texto.getText()) + valor; //Valor = 10
                    System.out.println(" " +cantidad);
                   * ventana.texto.setText(" ");
                   * ventana.texto.setText(""+ cantidad);
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Ingrese una moneda valida");
                    break;
            }
```

Comment: Agradezco que se haya tomado el tiempo para poder dar respuesta a mi pregunta, intenté modificarlo de la manera en la que usted indica, sin embargo al momento de la ejecucion me manda un error no se en que consita la verdad, creo haber modificado el codigo de manera correcta..

Comment: uhm quisiera poder mostrate como quedo mi codigo y el error que marca en la consola pero no se como ponerlo :/

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

Comment: Es que no tienes que hacer todo el código en consola, solo tienes que agregar las lineas que tienen un * en tu programa, espero y puedas arreglarlo

Answer (score 0):

Mira para el primer caso cuando ingrese una moneda de 1 peso intenta con esto y solo prueba que sume de 1 en 1 :

```
 contador = Integer.parseInt(cambio.getText()) + 1 ;
                    contadorTotal =  contadorTotal + contador ;
                    cambio.setText(" ");
                    cambio.setText(""+contadorTotal);
```

si te funciona solo cambia en los demás casos el valor de la moneda, los demás de contador1 al contador4 no le entiendo por que lo haces y al igual cuando los multiplicas por cantidadA.

Comment: si ya logro que me sume las monedas de un mismo case pero no me regresa la suma de todas las monedas